# Massive Thirring model as continuum limit of Heisenberg model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lattice-model, spin-models

The massive Thirring model

$S = \int d^2 x \left[ \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \partial_{\mu} \psi - m \bar{\psi} \psi - \frac{g}{2} \left( \bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \psi \right) \left(\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi \right) \right] $,

for Dirac fermions $\psi$ and their adjoints $\bar{\psi} = i \psi \gamma^0$, $\left\{ \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \right\} = 2 \eta^{\mu \nu}$, with $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ the Minkowski metric, $m$ and $g$ bare mass and coupling constants respectively, is supposed to be a continuum limit of the Heisenberg spin chain

$H = - \sum_{i, \alpha} J_\alpha S^\alpha_{i} S^\alpha_{i+1}$

where $S^\alpha_{i}$ are spin-1/2 operators proportional to interaction strengths $J_\alpha$. This correspondence is apparently made here, for example:https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.14.2153.

This, as I understand, means that introducing some lattice spacing $a$, correspondences

$J_\alpha \to f_\alpha(a, g, m)$

are to be made such that the vaccuum n-point functions of the massive Thirring model (with m and g) are recovered as the ground state correlation functions of the Heisenberg chain in the limit $a \to 0$.

What are the specific correspondences that must be made? I have an infinite chain in mind, but bonus points for discussing the finite-size case where the sum in the Heisenberg model is from $0$ to $L$, the functions $f_\alpha \to f_\alpha(L, a, g, m)$, and the limits to be taken are $L \to \infty$ and then $a \to 0$.

Comment: Are you having trouble reading the paper? The parameter $\beta^2$ that appears there comes from the sin-Gordon model, and it is related to $g$ in equation (4.22) of Coleman's paper (reference 2 of the paper you linked to).

Comment: @octonion The problem I'm having is with figuring out where the various factors of the lattice spacing (s in the paper) need to go, and what needs to be held constant, while the continuum limit is taken in order to approach a particular two-point function. I do get the sense this question is answered in the paper, but unfortunately I indeed am having some trouble extracting the information from it.